# Java EE web app, optimize queries

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, optimization

I'm building a Java EE web application using Servlets.

In a servlet I need to perform a series (30) of queries to an Oracle Database.

The queries are all of this type: **count(*) from TABLE where CONDITIONS**.

Each query takes 1 second, not too much, but the total amount of time is 30-35 seconds: that's too much!

Have you got any idea how I could improve the performances of my queries?

Is there a way to run them in parallel?

Comment: You could run them in parallel, but you should first analyze the queries and add the necessary indices on the table.

Comment: unluckily I cannot modify the DB tables or create indeces... :(

Comment: Frankly, if someone imposes you such absurd restrictions, he should expect bad performance, and shouldn't complain about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make one query of the 30:

```
select
  (select count(*) from tbl_table1 where ...) as table1_cnt,
  (select count(*) from tbl_table2 where ...) as table2_cnt,
  ...
  (select count(*) from tbl_table30 where ...) as table30_cnt
from dual;
```

If this doesn't help and you cannot alter the db, one thing remained. Cache your query results at Java side, in the cache keep track of your insert/delete operations made by the Java application, and time-by-time refresh your cache from db in the background using a scheduler.

Comment: If you cannot alter the db, one thing remained. Cache your query results at Java side, keep track of your insert/delete operations in the cache, and refresh your cache from db in the background using a scheduler.  (I ADDED THIS COMMENT TO THE ANSWER.)